# Empty array, which when expanded have objects, after POST fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making the 2024 game with the Hexes and I have a RNG server, which gives me the random coordinates and values for new blocks whenever button is clicked. The problem is that, when I make and POST fetch for this data and I remove the promise, I end up with an array, which does not exactly work as one.[This is how it looks in console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnUQD.png)

The code is

```
  let cellsValueArray = [];
  
  async function callAsync(radius, cellsWithValue=[]) {
    let startGameCells = [];
    let filledCells = startGameCells.concat(cellsWithValue);
    let rawResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:13337/${radius}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(filledCells),
    })
    let content = await rawResponse.json();
    cellsValueArray.push.apply(cellsValueArray, content);
  };
  callAsync(radius);
```

I want to have an ability to do stuff with this array like array.x array.y array.value,
to change the value of hex objects on the DOM. I tried array[0].x, which sometimes works, but the return Error( cannot assign methods to undefined). So array[0] returns undefined.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but this is very unclear... How does your array "not exaclty work as one"? What you're showing in the console is a regular array. And where exactly are you getting the undefined error? As `fetch` is async maybe you're trying to access `array[0]` when the array is stil empty.

Comment: I get the undefined error, when I try to console.log(array[0].x) to read the value of x coordinate in first element of an array. When I try to array.length It returns 0. Shouldn't it be a normal array, after I await for response in the function?